# Send email with grep result using crontab?

Tags: email, unix, grep, cron

To track the VPS traffic usage.

I tried command in terminal:

`(ifconfig|grep GiB) | mail -s "Traffic Usage" -t test@ahxxm.com -aFrom:ahxxm@ahxxm.com`

It successfully sent RX&TX info.

But when added to crontab:

```
0 5 * * * (ifconfig|grep GiB) | mail -s "Traffic Usage" -t test@ahxxm.com -aFrom:ahxxm@ahxxm.com
```

It failed to send the grep result, instead, it sent blank email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PATHs set between your command-line testing and the crontab are not the same.

From command-line, do `which ifconfig` and `which mail`, maybe even `which grep`. Then use those fully-qualified paths in your crontab. i.e.

**revised**
Per reminder from tripleee, there is really no need to create a sub-shell (sing `( cmds )`. The most efficient solution is to remove the sub-shell characters, i.e.

```
0 5 * * * /path/to/ifconfig | /path/to/grep GiB | /path/to/mail -s "Traffic Usage" -t test@ahxxm.com -aFrom:ahxxm@ahxxm.com
```

While for your particular case, the extra "cost" of invoking a sub-shell is minimal, it is really that your setting a bad habit, that if you carry over to all scripting (like inside of a while loop), could affect the performance of your processing. So best to only use sub-shells when you really need them.

If for some reason you are using this question as a place holder for a more complex problem that really requires a sub-shell to send output to the `mail` command, then I leave the original solution in place. (But I can't think of a reason you would need a sub-shell in a process chain that is being run from a crontab).

```
0 5 * * * (/path/to/ifconfig|/path/to/grep GiB) | /path/to/mail -s "Traffic Usage" -t test@ahxxm.com -aFrom:ahxxm@ahxxm.com
```

Or you can search here to see how to modify your crontab environment so it's PATH will include the required paths and there will be no need to change your crontab entry.

BUT, adding PATHs to `crontab` entries can be very different between one OS and another, so be sure to search specific to your OS. I'm thinking mostly of old-line Unix, like Sun, AIX, and other vendor systems not Linux.

IHTH

Comment: @SnoopyGuo :  See my edit for how you can accept this answer.

Comment: The subshell (i. e. the parentheses around the first two commands) is unnecessary.